# Auto correct words as user types

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

So playing with jquery autocorrect.

And it works great example:

```
var defaults = {
        corrections: {
            gr8: "great",
            taht: "that",
            ur : "you are",
            arent: "are not"
    }
};
```

So as user types the word gr8 the script listens for spacebar, and once detected alters the word to its correct replacement.

The issue I have is, we dont want to use word replacements, we want to use unicode replacement similar to this:

```
 var defaults = {
        corrections: {
            rain: 'u+2602;'
    }
};
```

So if the user types the word rain it gets replaced with the u+2602 ( but displays the ascii image )

What am I doing wrong, I presume its because this type of script can only parse strings..

Original script [here](http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2009/06/22/jquery-auto-correct-plugin/)

I dont need anyone to create this for us, just want to know how to echo the symbol .

Comment: I really don't know JavaScript, but shouldn't this be a escape sequence? maybe something like `"\u+2602"`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to just use `'\u2602'` and have that do the Right Thing.

Comment: perfect you saved me from insanity !